# How can a function/script tell Xterm from Terminology?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to have a function in `.bash_login` that displays text if the current terminal is XTerm, but NOT Terminology. When I do `echo $TERM` in Terminology, it outputs `xterm` How can I tell them apart?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the 'right' way to do it, but you could find what command the parent terminal was invoked with by calling `ps` with parent process ID obtained via the shell builtin `$PPID` e.g.

```
# get the shell's parent command from the PPID via ps
pcomm=$(ps -ocomm= $PPID)
```

You can then test the value of the command string - for example using a case statement

```
# now do something based on the value of the parent terminal command
case "$pcomm" in
  "gnome-terminal")
  echo "parent is gnome-terminal"
  ;;
  "xterm")
  echo "parent is xterm"
  ;;
  "terminator")
  echo "parent is terminator"
  ;;
  *)
  echo "unknown parent terminal"
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a another (simpler IMO) way of doing it. I don't have enlightenment, so I can't test it on Terminology, but I did test it with gnome-terminal, terminator and xterm.

```
terminalPID=$(ps -o ppid= $PPID) # get the script's parent's PID (the terminal)
processName=$(ps -p $terminalPID -o comm=) # get the terminal's name by it's PID
terminalName='gnome-terminal' # specify what process name you want to check for

# do the checking

if [ $processName == $terminalName ] ; then 
    echo "You are using gnome-terminal!"
else 
    echo "You are using something else!"
fi
```

Now in order to figure out your terminal's process name, open your terminal and run

```
ps -p $PPID -o comm=
```

This will print out the terminal's process name (providing you are running bash of course).

A fuller version that checks for several different terminal emulator's I have installed:

```
terminalPID=$(ps -o ppid= $PPID) # get the script's parent's PID (the terminal)
processName=$(ps -p $terminalPID -o comm=) # get the terminal's name by it's PID

# do the checking

if [ $processName == 'gnome-terminal' ] ; then 
    echo "You are using gnome-terminal!"
elif [ $processName == 'xterm' ] ; then
    echo "You are using xterm!"
elif [ $processName == '/usr/bin/termin' ] ; then
    echo "You are using Terminator!"
else 
    echo "You are using something else!"
fi
```